# html/javascript file display in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, html, reactjs, jupyter

To display html files in a jupyter notebook/lab environment, I am aware that one can simply call

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame('project/dummy.html', width=200, height=300)
```

to display the corresponding html file called dummy.html. This succeeds for simple standalone html files.

I would like to explore the possibility of embedding a webapp I have built using React, in a jupyter environment. The file that I would need to load into jupyter is an index.html file that links to a static folder containing javascript and css files. Instead of displaying this webapp, I receive the following error in the browser:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

How would one circumvent this issue?